# Find the angle of intersection of circles $x^2+y^2-6x+4=0 \ \&\ x^2+y^2-2x-2y-8=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the angle of  intersection of circles $$x^2+y^2-6x+4=0 \\  x^2+y^2-2x-2y-8=0$$

my answer is : 41.14 degrees. but i'm not sure if it's right. please help me.

Comment: It would help if you show what you did.  Then someone can tell you that you're fine or spot any error you may have made.  What did you find for the intersection points, and how did you find the slopes of the two circles at those locations?

Comment: You should tell us the point of intersection. Ordinarily, by the way, an instructor would be looking for an answer of the form $\arctan(\text{some rational number})$

Comment: Using dot-product of the tangent vectors at both intersections, I have $ \ \cos \theta \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ \Rightarrow \ \theta \ = \ 45º \ . $

Comment: I drew a triangle with one vertex at the center of the large circle, one vertex at the center of the small circle, and one vertex at the intersection point. All three side lengths are known. Law of cosines gives $45^\circ$.

Comment: $(4\mid 2)$ and $(2\mid -2)$

Comment: http://www.had2know.com/academics/intersection-angle-two-circles.html

Comment: The calculus tags seem inappropriate. [tag:analytic-geometry] seems to be a better tag.

Comment: @robjohn Well her teacher might have intended for her to use calculus instead of trig to solve the problem, especially since the specification of the circles was Cartesian instead of geometric (lengths).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

I suppose that the problem can be addressed in a simple manner if the the points of intersection are known.

If you substract the first equation for the second, terms $x^2$ and $y^2$ disappear and you just have linear relation between $x$ and $y$; from this, you can extract $$y=2 (x-3)$$ I now you replace $y$ by this value in the first equation, you end with a quadratice equation in $x$ which is $$5 x^2-30 x+40=0$$ the roots of which being $x=2$ and $x=4$. So, the intersection points are ($2,-2$) and ($4,2$).

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Subtracting quadratics is a dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Write the equations as
$$
(x-3)^2+y^2=5
$$
and
$$
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=10
$$
Thus, we have a triangle with sides $\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{10}$, $\sqrt{5}$:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The Law of Cosines says
$$
5=5+10-2\sqrt{5}\sqrt{10}\cos(\alpha)
$$
which implies
$$
\cos(\alpha)=\frac1{\sqrt2}
$$
We could also recognize the $45{-}45{-}90$ triangle.

Comment: It should be noted that $\alpha$ is not the angle of intersection, but it is very helpful for finding the angle of intersection.

Comment: @DanielV: well, the angle between the normals is the angle between the tangents.

Comment: @DanielV: the angle of the intersection of two curves is ambiguous. It could mean either of two supplementary angles. I assume this is what you were intending (having read your link in comment to the question).

Comment: Yes I think it would be nice to show the tangents on the diagram so that it's apparent how 45 degrees solves the problem.

Comment: Nice to show the diagram, by the way!

Comment: @robjohn You are right, I hadn't noticed the ambiguity, thanks.